# add prefix to files with rename - error argument too long

Tags: ssh, rename, prefix

I have thousands of files inside a directory I need to rename adding a prefix like "th_" so that files will be th_65461516846.jpg
but I can't due to the error "argument too long"

I have used this command

rename 's/^/th_/' *

thanks!

Comment: How long is the full path with the resulting filename? https://fogbugz.bitvise.com/default.asp?WinSSHD.1.3867.1

Comment: Which shell are you using? It is hard to tell from your description if a file name is too long or the expansion of `*` is. On StackOverflow it is important to give the precise error; for example if the error message "Argument list too long" is very different from "Filename too long". My answer assumes you got the former error message.

Comment: argument too long ad in too many files. sorry I am new at all this

Answer (score 0):

The [xargs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) program is used to break command lines into multiple commands to avoid blowing the shell line length limit. In your case, you'd use:

```
ls | xargs rename 's/^/th_/'
```

Which repeatedly executes `rename` with a portion of the output of `ls` until the list of files is exhausted. Do be aware this idiom requires special attention if the file names have spaces or other funny characters in them (which I'm assuming isn't so based on your example).

Comment: I actually tested the rename 's/^/th_/' * into a sample directory with only 3 files and id didn't work

Comment: for i in * ; do mv $i th_${i#} ; done

It gave me a message after a while like "mv: target `.jpg' is not a directory" but it kept working and it renamed.

Answer (score 0):

This one did the job

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f/9/th_}";done
```

or

```
for f in * ; do mv $f th_${f#} ; done
```

I don't know what differs between the 2 but in my case they both work.